# (Imacross) Extract Text from _Xpath_ no extract content from Class under Javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath, text, extract, imacros

Using this code under imacros 9.0.3 running on Firefox 55 works very well extracting the text from the class

```
TAG XPATH="//div[contains(@class,'col-md-12 text-center alert alert-danger')]" EXTRACT=TXT
```

But if you implement the same situation on Javascript Running Imacros, it stops working

```
var macro;
macro = "CODE:";

macro += "TAG XPATH="//div[contains(@class,'col-md-12 text-center alert alert-danger')]" EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";

iimPlay(macro)
iimDisplay(result);
```

I have also used in another more explicit way the location where I need to extract the content, but even so it does not work using the code in java

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following script should work:

```
var macro;
macro = "CODE:";

macro += 'TAG XPATH="//div[contains(@class,\'col-md-12 text-center alert alert-danger\')]" EXTRACT=TXT' + "\n";

iimPlay(macro);
iimDisplay(iimGetExtract());
```